# accessing validation rules in associated model (CakePHP)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Hi I have been trying to access the validation rules of an associated model from my main controller. It doesn't seem to be working and I haven't been able to find any reference about this. Here is what I am trying to do:

User Controller snip:

```
$this->User->TalentProfile->set( $this->data );
if ($this->User->TalentProfile->validates()) {
    //it always validates and doesn't seem to see model's validation rules
}
```

TalentProfile Model snip:

```
var $validate = array (
        'first_name' => array(
            'maxLength' => array(
                    'rule' => array('maxLength', 20),  
                    'message' => 'Can not be longer than 20 characters.',
                    'last' => true
            ),
            'first_name_not_empty' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                    'message' => 'This field is required',
                    'last' => true
            ),
        ),
);
```

I have also tried rewrapping the array my thought being that the model name could be screwing with the validation:

```
$this->User->TalentProfile->set( array('TalentProfile',$this->data) ) );
```

I have also tried this hoping but still same results:

```
$this->loadModel('TalentProfile');
$this->TalentProfile->set( $this->data) );
```

There is something I am missing. Please help! Thanks

EDIT:

I tried to save the form data which is giving me blanks in the SQL. I think this might be a simpler problem than I thought.

Comment: Could you use `debug($this->data)` before your `validates()` function and post the results?

Comment: it is all blanks to test blank checking. Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [fname] => 
            [mname] => 
            [lname] => 
        )

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the $validate array in the `TalentProfile` model, you require data to be of the form:

```
Array(
    [TalentProfile] => Array(
        [first_name] =>
    )
)
```

A little explanation on how this works:

In the call `$this->User->TalentProfile->validates()` and `$this->TalentProfile->validates()` you are using the validation methods in the `TalentProfile` model. This means that CakePHP is going to validate your input data against the validation rules in that model, so it expects the `TalentProfile` key to be set in the array (but dies down quietly if it's not).

In your `$validates` array, you have set up validation rules for a key called `first_name`. CakePHP takes this key as a field name that is being input from a form.

Right now, you are taking inputs as `fname` instead of `first_name`. Your inputs are also associated with the `User` model, and not `TalentProfile`.

If you explain further what you're trying to do with your form, I can be of more help.

Comment: you are a saint! I am an idiot. I can't believe I didn't realize my input names were off! THANK YOU

Comment: Oh and what is going on is I am handling all the controller tasks in the user controller but validating against the variables that will be used in a profile that will be saved several pages in.